# Port forwarding gets me to router login page

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I have port forwarding configured on a Teltonika RUT240.

The plan is to connect to a device on the local network. Connecting to the public IP (static IP from ISP) only gets me to the router's web page.

I have tried entering trough port 8082 and 80 but it's all the same.

Port is forwarded to the local IP and port 80.

If I enter the devices Local IP when I am connected to the Local network I can access the page without a problem, but when I try to enter from outside I get to the Router WEB page.

Port forwarding rules:

- Protocol: UDP/TCP
- External port: 80/8082/etc...
- internal zone: LAN
- internal IP: Devices local IP address

Note that previously we were accessing the device in the same way(trough web browser) and access was working fine. We have since changed the router and access is not working.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How exactly have you set the port forwarding rule(s) and to which device's IP? And you want to connect to *what* in that device, exactly?

Comment: I have set it to port 80 on the local devices IP. I would like to connect to its WEB configuration page. If i enter its IP in the browser when i am connected to the local network i get access to the page. but when i try to enter from outside, connecting trough static public IP and port forwarding rule I only get to the router WEB page. For protocol - TCP/UDP, external port - 8082/80/etc.., internal zone - LAN, internal IP adress - local device IP adress, internal port - 80.

Comment: 1. Please accept the edit I've made to improve your question then 2. Do *another* [edit] to add the information you just gave in the comment above. New info and/or replies to requests for clarification or additional info should always de edited in the question, not just comments. While at that please understand 1. that's likely not possible at all and 2. you don't port forward to the same device that's port forwarding.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to IT. What do you mean with the last two sentences? Isn't the port forwarding device in this case Teltonika and I am port forwarding to Local device?

Comment: Are your connection attempts to the router's IP *actually* made from outside or from within the same network as the local device? (The point being that merely using the public IP address is not enough to actually make it "from outside" and that very often trips people up.)

Comment: Yes, im in the office now and I can only access the router. Before, when i was on the location at the device, plugged in the switch I was able to access the Devices WEB page.

Comment: Most routers do not allow accessing its settings from outside. In those that do the feature is disabled by default. Please check your user's manual. In any case it's not a matter of port forwarding as said feature is used to route external access to another device connected to router, never to the router itself.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I think that's the exact opposite of what OP is looking for

Comment: @u1686_grawity I think the answer is correct for the intended purpose. Why do you think what I commented is the opposite? The OP wasn't clear about it probably because they don't grasp the terminology but they're actually asking about RMS while thinking it has something to do with port forwarding.

Comment: Please post screenshots from the router setup - you can use your phone to make them.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, the RUT240 has RMS ([Remote Management System](https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/RUT240_Remote_Monitoring_%26_Administration)) with HTTP/S  access. You should be able to go into

```
System -> Administration -> Access Control
```

[image]

Then either turn off remote HTTP access or change the port from 80.

As a side note, you should be putting everything behind SSL on port 443. You can do that with a free SSL using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. We have solved the problem.
Trouble was that the gateway of the device was configured wrong, once we put Teltonika as gateway it has started working. Thank you all for your time.